# Eway Payment Gateway Not work in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, onestepcheckout, php-7.2

I am facing error

```
{"error":"Error happened when getting access code, please try again later"}
```

AND

- http://cityflowersales.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
  400 as I am using eway 3.0.5 with magento 2.3.0 and php 7.2.

before I was used magento 2.1 with eway 2.0 but faced same issue like now so I had decided to upgrade magento and eway but still facing same issue.

**Request URL:**

```
http://cityflowersales.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
```

**REQUEST :**

```
{"cartId":"709","billingAddress":{"customerAddressId":"14","countryId":"AU","regionId":"0","regionCode":null,"region":null,"customerId":"515","street":["Centenary

Hospital for Women & Children","Cnr Yamba & Hindmarsh
Drives"],"telephone":"0262442222","postcode":"2617","city":"Bruce","firstname":"fgfg","lastname":"fgfg","saveInAddressBook":null},"paymentMethod":{"method":"ewayrapid","additionalData":{"SecuredCardData":"A1001pI0XNF-rDHd8HELWsbU4dZObqkdF9MvX5uMcLGuoM2u42tcCRNDkhxFv8L15WZG0","TokenID":1,"TokenAction":"use"}}}
```

**RESPONSE :**

```
{"message":"Transaction has been declined. Please try again later."}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.

It was due to mismatch currency setup in my magento site admin so matched with EWAY account setting and payment works :)